# How to delete folders with common string windows batch

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, wildcards

I have a directory of of subdirectories as such:

- test1_2015_1
- test1_2015_2
- test1_2013_1
- test1_2013_1
- test1_2012_3
- test1_2015_1
- test1_2016_1

I want to delete all folders with containing "2015". I have done this:

```
[Some processing code]

set free_space=13
set minimum=25

if %free_space% leq %minimum% (
    echo "inside else"
    echo "You've reached capacity, deleting workspace files..."
    cd /D d:\jenkins\workspace
    dir
    for /D %f in (*2015*) do @rmdir %f /Q /S
    echo "Completed workspace file deletion..."
)
```

This should take care of it because when I run it manually on that machine, it works but running it as a script I get this error:

```
f was unexpected at this time.
```

What is going on here?

Comment: `/S` is for recursion, `/Q` is to continue without being prompted and the `@` is to make rmdir silent

Comment: You need to use `%%f` inside a batch file, `%f` is for the command line.